# How to make an array from a class, with the void function

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor, destructor

The problem is I am making a program that will take 5 bank accounts of which the user inputs 5 different sets of names and amount. It will take those sets, put them into an array. and display them.
I am setting up an array that will ask for inputs for 3 inputs, firstname, lastname, and amount. it will take them and put them into an array for each. But when i try to call it, i get an error.

I tried to call it by trying to do void `readCustomer(bankAccount users[]);` but that doesn't work either. I am stumped how to call it.

```
   const int ARR_SIZE = 5;

   class bankAccount{
   private:
   string firstname, lastname, initials;
   int accountNum, amount;
   public:
   void readCustomer(); //will get inputs and store them 
   into an array.   
   };

   int main(){
   bankAccount users[ARR_SIZE];
   for (i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++){
    users[i].readCustomer();
       }

   }

   void bankAccount::readCustomer(){
   amount = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++){
    cout << "Reading data for customer" << endl;
    cout << "First Name: ";
    cin >> users[i].firstname;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Last Name: ";
    cin >> users[i].lastname;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Amount: ";
    cin >> users[i].amount;
    cout << endl;
    }

    }
```

I was expecting to get `cout`s and `cin`s to call for firstname, lastname to be put into an array. But I get this error:

> In function 'int main()':
>   16:8: error: request for member 'readCustomer' in 'users', which is of non-class type 'bankAccount [5]'
>   16:33: error: expected primary-expression before 'users'

For which I have no idea what it means.

Comment: The error message literally says " you are trying to call a method on an array, I don't know how to do that." To fix the immediate problems: 1) make `readCustomer`static so you can call it as `bankAccount::readCustomer(users)` (note `::` instead of `.`) OR make `readCustomer` a regular function outside of `bankAccount`. 2) readCustomer does not know the size of the array it receives. You should either pass the size separately, or use a smarter collection such as `std::vector<bankAccount>` or `std::array<bankAccount, ARR_SIZE>`

Comment: You need to read some more about the fundamentals of how to write and use functions, and about arrays, in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll recommend that you use a c++ container instead of a c-style array. For instance a `std::vector`. Using a vector will for instance let you change the total number of accounts at run time instead of the fixed size (aka 5) that you have now.

But the fundamental problem with your code is the same so this answer will also use the c-style array.

The problem is (IMO) a design issue. When you make a class named `bankAccount`, it shall represent **a single** account. In other words, such a class shall have no knowledge about arrays. Then you can make another class that represents a collection of accounts or simply make an array of accounts.

It may look like:

```
   class bankAccount{
   public:
       string firstname, lastname, initials;
       int accountNum, amount;
       void readCustomer();  // no argument
   };

   int main(){
       bankAccount users[ARR_SIZE];
       for (int i=0; i<ARR_SIZE; ++i)
       {
           users[i].readCustomer();
        // ^^^^^^^^
        // This part gets you the bankAccount instance at index i of the array.
        // The ".readCustomer()" then calls the function on that specific
        // bankAccount instance
       }
   }

   void bankAccount::readCustomer(){
        // read/initialize information for the account
        // Example:
        // Initialize amount to zero
        amount = 0;
   }
```

Comment: So i tried to change it to your way, but i tried to do a for loop inside of readCustomer,  doing cin >> users[i].firstname, and such. But i get an error telling me it was not declared in the scope. **ALSO, the strings and int for bankAccouint, ARE PRIVATE, not public. My apologies.

Comment: @lowmask2 Well, as I write in the answer: `readCustomer` shall **not** know about the array (IMO). So don't loop inside `readCustomer`. Just read the data for **a single customer**. In other words: Don't do `cin >> users[i].firstname` but just do `cin >> firstname`. If you really want a functions that reads all accounts in a loop, that can be done. But in that case you won't put the function in the `class bankAccount` but in another class that represents a collection (aka array/vector/list) of `bankAccount`.